# Sliding window (shift) for an array

Tags: .net, shift-register

I've got a low-level keyboard hook which currently allows me to control a media player from inside any application, including games.

It works by looking at the specific keystroke captured.

I'd like to extend it to look for combinations of keys. I can hardcode some logic but I feel there must be a more logical way.

Really, I'm looking for something like a shift register...

eg as I type "BlahPlay", I'd like a structure which can be used like this...

```
[_,_,_,_]
[_,_,_,B]
[_,_,B,l]
[_,B,l,a]
[B,l,a,h]
[l,a,h,P]
[a,h,P,l]
[h,P,l,a]
[P,l,a,y] <-- detect "Play"
```

Short of looping and shifting the items in an array, what's the correct way to do this?

The best I can think of right now is ...

```
Private Register(4) As Char
Private Position = 0 

Sub Add(Character as Char)
    Register(Position) = Character
    Position = (Position + 1) Mod Register.Length
End Sub

Function Get() as String
    Dim Ret As New StringBuilder
    For i = Position To Position + Register.Length
        Ret.Append(Register(i Mod Register.Length)
    Next
    Return Ret.ToString
End Function
```

Comment: Sounds like a [Queue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977ey2c.aspx) might work here.

Comment: @keyboardP Maybe if there's an unconventional way to use it? But I need to be able to query the state of the register as a whole, ideally without dequeueing/requeueing every time. I also want a maximum size so that new values force out old ones. I'll improve my example

Comment: Maybe this [circular buffer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1213317/maximum-capacity-collection-in-c-sharp) might be helpful.

Comment: How about an integer. No really: you could let every byte in the integer be an ascii character / keycode. Shifting/adding in a new char is trivial, just `state * 256 + Character` (that's equivalent to shifting left by 8 and orring the new char in). Comparing all four characters with, say, `{P, l, a, y}` is trivial, just compare the integer with a known integer constant (0x506C6179 in the case of Play).

Comment: @harold That's an interesting approach but it shows some promise... I took a 4-char command as an example but off the top of my head, I can't imagine a scenario requiring more than 8 so it may well be a viable option. I'll leave this open in case of a better solution but thanks for the idea, I wouldn't have considerd it myself

Answer (score 1):

Instead of *shifting* the items in the buffer, you could create standard array and just inserting each item in the next position, looping around as necessary. Consider the following code:

```
var buffSize = 4;
var position = 0;
var buffer = new char[buffSize];
```

Now you simply insert every new character at `position` and set `position = (position + 1) % buffSize` every time a new key is entered. Suppose you typed `abcPlay`, the buffer would be:

```
[_,_,_,_] position = 0
[a,_,_,_] position = 1
[a,b,_,_] position = 2
[a,b,c,_] position = 3
[a,b,c,P] position = 0
[l,b,c,P] position = 1
[l,a,c,P] position = 2
[l,a,y,P] position = 3
```

This means that instead of simply reading each char out from the begin reading at `position`. For example, if you're testing to see if the buffer contains `Play`, you'd have to do something like this:

```
var test = new char[] { 'P', 'l', 'a', 'y' };
int p = (position + buffSize - test.Length) % buffSize;
bool success = true;
for(int i = 0; i < test.Length; i++)
{
    if (buffer[p] != test[i])
    {
        success = false;
        break;
    }

    p = (p + 1) % buffSize;
}
```

**Edit** You edited your question since I began writing this answer. It appears that you've already developed a solution pretty close to this. I'd still recommend going with something like this. It will be more efficient than shifting each item in the array on every insert.

Comment: Yeah, sorry for that - I thought I should add more detail after the first comment - but it's gratifying to see that I'm not the only one thinking of that approach. I have to admit I'm surprised that there isn't a more "standard" way to do this - after all, shift registers are pretty fundamental to µProcessors... If I don't find a better solution, I'll accept. Thanks for taking the time to respond