# How would I convert one generic collection to another type of generic collection in c#

Tags: c#, generics

I am in an environment that contains a `RollingWindow` class where `RollingWindow<T>` can be a collection of any type/object.

I would like to create a C# method to convert a `RollingWindow<T>` into a `List<T>`.

Essentially I'd use it in the following manner:

```
List<int> intList = new List<int>();
List<Record> = recordList = new List<Record>();
RollingWindow<int> intWindow = new RollingWindow<int>(20); //20 elements long
RollingWindow<Record> = recordWindow = new RollingWindow<Record>(10); //10 elements long

ConvertWindowToList(intList, intWindow); // will populate intList with 20 elements in intWindow
ConvertWindowToList(intList, intWindow); // will populate recordList with 10 elements in recordWindow
```

Any thoughts on how I would do this in c#?

Comment: Can you clarify on this `RollingWindow` class. Is it custom? Is it inherited from `IEnumerable`?

Comment: Is it something like http://stackoverflow.com/a/1213761/2130976?

Comment: It is defined in the environment that I happen to be working in. I believe it is inherited from IEnumerable but I am not 100%.

Comment: If `RollingWindow<T>` implements `IEnumerable<T>` then this will work: `intList = intWindow.ToList()`.

Comment: Is there any `recordWindow.ToList()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the assumption that `RollingWindow<T>` implements `IEnumerable<T>` then;

```
List<int> intList = intWindow.ToList();
List<Record> recordList = recordWindow.ToList();
```

will work

Answer (score -1):

I assume that the `RollingWindow<T>` is derived from `IEnumerable<T>`.

So this could be possible:

```
var enumerableFromWin = (IEnumerable<int>) intWindow;
intList = new List<int>(enumerableFromWin);

var enumRecFromWin = (IEnumerable<Record>) recordWindow;
recordList = new List<Record>(enumRecFromWin);
```