# c# collection with automatic item removal

Tags: c#, collections

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Fixed size queue which automatically dequeues old values upon new enques](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5852863/fixed-size-queue-which-automatically-dequeues-old-values-upon-new-enques)

Is there such a thing as a collection that will automatically drop old items as new items are added?  Let's say that I have a list that is limited to ten items.  Upon adding an eleventh item, the first is removed, and the capacity remains at ten.  Seems like there would be such a thing, but I can't find it.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One possible way to achieve your goal:

```
public class FixedSizedQueue<T> : Queue<T>
{
    private readonly int maxQueueSize;
    private readonly object syncRoot = new object();

    public FixedSizedQueue(int maxQueueSize)
    {
        this.maxQueueSize = maxQueueSize;
    }

    public new void Enqueue(T item)
    {
        lock (syncRoot)
        {
            base.Enqueue(item);
            if (Count > maxQueueSize)
                Dequeue(); // Throw away
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, custom coding was the first thing I did, but then i wondered..........

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this through custom coding, have a look at

```
//Lets suppose Customer is your custom class 
   public class CustomerCollection : CollectionBase 
    { 
        public Customer this[int index] 
        {
            get
            {
                return (Customer) this.List[index]; 
            } 
            set 
            { 
                this.List[index] = value;
            }
        }
        public void Add(Customer customer)
        { 
           if(this.List.Count > 9)
               this.List.RemoveAt(0);         
           this.List.Add(customer);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

AFIK, such a collection does not exist.  You are going to have to roll your own.  One possibility is deriving from `ObservableCollection<T>` and use the `CollectionChanged` event to remove "old" items

Answer (score -1):

The above answers are correct ; you have to write your own code .

However , you can acheive this using reference counting .  The [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/hi-in/magazine/bb985010%28en-us%29.aspx) says how .NET does the garbage collection through reference counting. This is not required for a simple question like this, but it shall proabably help you in the long run.