# Concurrent Collection with max capacity

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, collections, .net-4.0

Is there any ready collection type in C# to support this scenario:

> I need to add from many threads, if the collection reached it's
>   maximum configured capacity, it will delete the oldest item and add
>   the new item.

Is this supported natively by some .NET 4.0 object, and if not, what is the best way to implement this?

**EDIT:**

I am searching in ConcurrentCollections but I couldn't find anything helpful!

Comment: You can wrap a [ConcurrentQueue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and expose a custom `Enqueue` method as shown here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5852863/fixed-size-queue-which-automatically-dequeues-old-values-upon-new-enques

Comment: Why down-voted! please comment when down-voting to know the problem.

Comment: I'm guessing because you've been given an answer in the comment section but your edit doesn't explain why it wasn't suitable for you so there's no other answer to give.