# Read a preceding line of a text file; if current line contains "X"

Tags: c#, text-files, streamreader

At the moment I have a file being read for a specific entry "X".
Once I find this entry I can do what I need to do in any following lines BUT there is a piece of information that is required 2 lines before the "X" appears. 
Right now I am able to use `var line = reader.ReadLine();` to move forward in the file and read lines that come after "X". How do I move back to read that data 2 lines before?

```
while (!reader.EndOfStream)
{
    var line = reader.ReadLine();

    if (line.Contains("X"))
    {
        Processing
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `StreamReader` you can use `File.ReadAllLines` which returns a string array:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("file.txt")
for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
{
    if (lines[i].Contains("X") && i >= 2)
    {
         string res = lines[i-2];
    } 
}
```

Comment: This answered my current question PLUS another for the bonus point

Answer (score 11):

Save it as you go along:

```
string prev1;
string prev2;

while (!reader.EndOfStream)
{

    var line = reader.ReadLine();

    if (line.Contains("X"))
    {
        Processing
    }

    prev2 = prev1;
    prev1 = line;
}
```

If you need more than this it could easily be converted into a queue that you push/pull from.

Comment: If I do that have I set the line to be ahead of the line containing "X" again? Would I need to bring the line back below "X" to prevent it being read again?

Comment: @user2399216: No - the actual file read itself is un affected, you're just caching previously read lines into memory as you go along.

Comment: It's breaking the loop. I need to continue checking the document for "X" as it is a Marker for unique results being presented. "X" will appear several times and its unique surrounding data will need to be collected each time

Comment: @user2399216: The looping style given would do that for each occurence of 'X' (ie capture the 2 rows prior to the row that contains X).

Answer (score 0):

Just store the last 2 lines read.

[Fixed size queue which automatically dequeues old values upon new enques](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5852863/fixed-size-queue-which-automatically-dequeues-old-values-upon-new-enques)

Answer (score 0):

Store the 2 previous lines :

```
string [] lineprev = new string[]{"",""} ;
while (!reader.EndOfStream)
{
    var line = reader.ReadLine();
    if (line.Contains("X"))
    {
        // Processing : Find info in lineprev[1]
    }
    lineprev[1]=lineprev[0] ;
    lineprev[0]= line ;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to keep previous line in memory, so you can access it, when you need.
Something like this:

```
var prev;
while (!reader.EndOfStream)
{
    var line = reader.ReadLine();

    if (line.Contains("X")) {
        // Processing both line and prev
    }

    prev = line; // remember previous line for future use
}
```