# ConcurrentQueue size limit and time frame

Tags: c#, concurrency, queue, concurrent-queue

I am looking for a way to :

1. read messages from a `ConcurrentQueue` limited to some size.
2. read not more then X message at a time frame.
   I want to stop the reading from Q once one of the 2 hit,
   until other code is done and do the same thing again.

I saw different implementation for Queue spill over,
in here [Fixed size queue which automatically dequeues old values upon new enqueues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5852863/fixed-size-queue-which-automatically-dequeues-old-values-upon-new-enques)
but can't figure out how to combine them correctly.

```
public class FixedSizedQueue<T>
{

    public int Size { get; private set; }

    public FixedSizedQueue(int size)
    {
        Size = size;
    }

    public void Enqueue(T obj)
    {
        queue.Enqueue(obj);

        while (queue.Count > Size)
        {
            T outObj;
            queue.TryDequeue(out outObj);
        }
    }
}
```