# Is there a built-in limited-length wrapped-list (end-wraps-to-start) where you can only access the last n elements added?

Tags: c#, .net

I need to keep elements in a list/array, so that I can access the last n elements. I.e. I add to it all the time, and should be able to get from it the last elements if needed. (Like a security camera only keeping the last n hours.) I was thinking of having a List or an array, and maintaining an index where the index wraps around.

But this seems like a useful construction so I was wondering if it already exists in .Net. No need to reinvent the wheel if it does.

So does such a thing exist built in to .Net?

**EDIT**

Apparently, there is a question of how to *implement* this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5852863/fixed-size-queue-which-automatically-dequeues-old-values-upon-new-enques). That question and top answers are from more than 10 years ago. That does not answer my question of whether it is *built-in* **today**. A **lot** of what we use today didn't exist then. Also, using Queue won't help because I need to be able to access every element (up to n), not only the last one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fixed size queue which automatically dequeues old values upon new enques](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5852863/fixed-size-queue-which-automatically-dequeues-old-values-upon-new-enques)

Comment: [BoundedChannel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.channels.channel.createbounded?view=net-6.0) is a specialized asynchronous collection for producer/consumer scenarios that can be configured to [drop the newest or oldest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.channels.boundedchannelfullmode?view=net-6.0) items when full

Comment: As for wrapping, that's called a circular buffer. If you google you'll find a lot of implementations. At its simplest, non-thread-safe form it can be just a fixed-length array that uses modulo arithmetic to determine the next index. Such a thing *doesn't* require a BCL implementation

Comment: If you search NuGet for `circular buffer` you'll get 17 hits. One of the libraries worth looking into is [C5](https://github.com/sestoft/C5) which contains dozens of advanced collections, including a [CircularQueue](https://github.com/sestoft/C5/blob/master/C5/Arrays/CircularQueue.cs) that uses a buffer internally.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos BoundedChannel seems like exactly what I was looking for. You can transform your comment into an answer. (I mentioned circular just because I assumed that's how it would be implemented.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This describes a [circular or ring buffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer). Implementing one is relatively easy and googling or searching NuGet returns many implementations, including the [CircularQueue](https://github.com/sestoft/C5/blob/master/C5/Arrays/CircularQueue.cs) in the C5 library.

For asynchronous operations, one can use a [BoundedChannel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.channels.channel.createbounded?view=net-6.0) configured with [BoundedChannelFullMode.DropOldest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.channels.boundedchannelfullmode?view=net-6.0):

```
var options=new BoundedChannelOptions 
    { 
        Capacity = 10,
        FullMode = BoundedChannelFullMode.DropOldest
    };
var channel=Channel.CreateBounded<float>(options);

var writer=channel.Writer;
while(!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
{
   var value=await getSomeValue(cancellationToken);
   await writer.WriteAsync(value,cancellationToken);
}
writer.Complete();
```

[Channels](https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/an-introduction-to-system-threading-channels) are specialized asynchronous queues for producer/consumer scenarios so their API and behavior is quite different from normal queues.

- Writers and readers (producers and consumers) use different APIs to write ([ChannelWriter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.channels.channelwriter-1?view=net-6.0) and read [ChannelReader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.channels.channelreader-1?view=net-6.0). The [Channel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.channels.channel-2?view=net-6.0) class itself has no useful members beyond the `Reader` and `Writer` properties
- Writing and reading are explicitly asynchronous.
- Both write and *read* order are preserved
- Channels can be unbounded or bounded. An unbounded channel can grow infinitely, which can be a problem when readers are slower than writers. With Bounded channels, once a channel reaches its upper bound it can block writers (asynchronously) or discard the oldest or newest item.

Channels are used eg in [SignalR server-to-client streaming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/streaming?view=aspnetcore-6.0) to produce server events. The doc example uses an unbounded *owned* channel, ie a channel whose lifetime is controlled by the producer method. That could easily be a bounded channel with DropOldest. This would be useful if we want to only send "fresh" events to potentially slow subscribers :

```
public ChannelReader<int> Counter(
    int count,
    int delay,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var options=new BoundedChannelOptions 
    { 
        Capacity = 10,
        FullMode = BoundedChannelFullMode.DropOldest
    };
    var channel=Channel.CreateBounded<int>(options);


    // We don't want to await WriteItemsAsync, otherwise we'd end up waiting 
    // for all the items to be written before returning the channel back to
    // the client.
    _ = WriteItemsAsync(channel.Writer, count, delay, cancellationToken);

    return channel.Reader;
}

private async Task WriteItemsAsync(
    ChannelWriter<int> writer,
    int count,
    int delay,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    Exception localException = null;
    try
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            await writer.WriteAsync(i, cancellationToken);

            // Use the cancellationToken in other APIs that accept cancellation
            // tokens so the cancellation can flow down to them.
            await Task.Delay(delay, cancellationToken);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        localException = ex;
    }
    finally
    {
        writer.Complete(localException);
    }
}
```

If we set capacity to `1` we get `Publish Latest` behavior :

```
public ChannelReader<int> CounterLatest(
    int count,
    int delay,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var options=new BoundedChannelOptions 
    { 
        Capacity = 1,
        FullMode = BoundedChannelFullMode.DropOldest
    };
    var channel=Channel.CreateBounded<int>(options);


    // We don't want to await WriteItemsAsync, otherwise we'd end up waiting 
    // for all the items to be written before returning the channel back to
    // the client.
    _ = WriteItemsAsync(channel.Writer, count, delay, cancellationToken);

    return channel.Reader;
}
```

A consumer uses the `ChannelReader and eg the` IAsyncEnumerable<>`returned by`ChannelReader.ReadAllAsync` to read messages:

```
async Task ConsumeAsync(ChannelReader<int> input,CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    await foreach(var msg in input.ReadAllAsync(cancellationToken))
    {
        await DoSomething(msg);
    }
}
```