# Ring Buffer in Java

Tags: java, buffer

I have a streaming time series, of which I am interested in keeping the last 4 elements, which means I want to be able to pop the first, and add to the end. Essentially what I need is a [**ring buffer**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer).

Which Java Collection is the best for this? Vector?

Comment: `LinkedList` seems like a reasonable choice for O(1) inserts and removes, do you need O(1) indexing, too?

Comment: Thread safe? Not thread safe? For removing from the end and adding in the beginning a LinkedList is usually the best option.

Comment: Also see [how-would-you-code-an-efficient-circular-buffer-in-java-or-c-sharp?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/590069/how-would-you-code-an-efficient-circular-buffer-in-java-or-c-sharp?lq=1)

Answer (score 103):

Consider [CircularFifoBuffer](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.2/org/apache/commons/collections/buffer/CircularFifoBuffer.html) from Apache [Common.Collections](http://commons.apache.org/collections/). Unlike [Queue](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html) you don't have to maintain the limited size of underlying collection and wrap it once you hit the limit.

```
Buffer buf = new CircularFifoBuffer(4);
buf.add("A");
buf.add("B");
buf.add("C");
buf.add("D"); //ABCD
buf.add("E"); //BCDE
```

CircularFifoBuffer will do this for you because of the following properties:

- CircularFifoBuffer is a *first in first out buffer with a fixed
  size* that replaces its oldest element if full.
- The removal order of a CircularFifoBuffer is based on the insertion
  order; elements are removed in the same order in which they were
  added. The iteration order is the same as the removal order.
- The add(Object), BoundedFifoBuffer.remove() and
  BoundedFifoBuffer.get() operations *all perform in constant time*.
  All other operations perform in linear time or worse.

However you should consider it's limitations as well - for example, you can't add missing timeseries to this collection because it doens't allow nulls.

NOTE: When using current [Common Collections](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/release_4_0.html) (4.*), you have to use Queue. Like this:

```
Queue buf = new CircularFifoQueue(4);
```

Comment: there seems now to be a version derived from the original Commons Collections which makes use of generics: http://sourceforge.net/projects/collections/ (it looks like the project was moved to github)

Comment: Commons Collections 4.0 includes [CircularFifoQueue](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections4/queue/CircularFifoQueue.html) which has the same properties, and supports generics.

Comment: I noticed the CircularFifoQueue doesn't work like this. When I put "HELLO" into a 3 unit sized Queue, I go from "HEL" to "LEL" to "LOL". What happened to the feature described by @AndryTaptunov?

Comment: That is the feature suggested by Andy. "heLlo" goes "heL" -> "leL" -> "loL" overwriting the oldest letter first.

Comment: Regardless of how one iterates through the [CircularFifoQueue](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-release/index.html) (by removing elements, using the queue's Iterator, directly indexing ascendingly from pos 0, etc.), you get the expected `heL`, `eLl`, `Llo`. So @RyanTheLeach seems to be illustrating how the queue is storing its elements, but I can't reproduce the behavior @E.S. described

Answer (score 53):

Since Guava 15.0 (released September 2013) there's [EvictingQueue](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/15.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/EvictingQueue.html):

> A non-blocking queue which automatically evicts elements from the head
>   of the queue when attempting to add new elements onto the queue and it
>   is full. An evicting queue must be configured with a maximum size.
>   Each time an element is added to a full queue, the queue automatically
>   removes its head element. This is different from conventional bounded
>   queues, which either block or reject new elements when full.
>
> This class is not thread-safe, and does not accept null elements.

Example use:

```java
EvictingQueue<String> queue = EvictingQueue.create(2);
queue.add("a");
queue.add("b");
queue.add("c");
queue.add("d");
System.out.print(queue); //outputs [c, d]
```

Comment: @MartinVseticka Yes, its O(1).

Answer (score 12):

If you need

- O(1) insertion and removal
- O(1) indexing to interior elements
- access from a single thread only
- generic element type

then you can use [this CircularArrayList for Java](http://www.museful.net/2011/software-development/circulararraylist-for-java) in this way (for example):

```
CircularArrayList<String> buf = new CircularArrayList<String>(4);

buf.add("A");
buf.add("B");
buf.add("C");
buf.add("D"); // ABCD

String pop = buf.remove(0); // A <- BCD
buf.add("E"); // BCDE

String interiorElement = buf.get(i);
```

All these methods run in O(1).

Comment: link is dead - domain is dead

Comment: @AntonyStubbs Thanks for alerting me. It was temporarily down after a nameserver migration.

Answer (score 11):

Since Java 1.6, there is `ArrayDeque`, which implements `Queue` and seems to be faster and more memory efficient than a `LinkedList` and doesn't have the thread synchronization overhead of the `ArrayBlockingQueue`: from the API docs: *"This class is likely to be faster than Stack when used as a stack, and faster than LinkedList when used as a queue."*

```
final Queue<Object> q = new ArrayDeque<Object>();
q.add(new Object()); //insert element
q.poll(); //remove element
```

Comment: This grows unbounded and doesn't behave like a ring buffer.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem some time ago and was disappointed because I couldn't find any solution that suites my needs so I wrote my own class. 
Honestly, I did found some code back then, but even that wasn't what I was searching for so I adapted it and now I'm sharing it, just like the author of that piece of code did.

EDIT: This is the original (although slightly different) code: [CircularArrayList for java](http://www.museful.net/2011/software-development/circulararraylist-for-java)

I don't have the link of the source because it was time ago, but here's the code:

```
import java.util.AbstractList;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.RandomAccess;

public class CircularArrayList<E> extends AbstractList<E> implements RandomAccess {

private final int n; // buffer length
private final List<E> buf; // a List implementing RandomAccess
private int leader = 0;
private int size = 0;


public CircularArrayList(int capacity) {
    n = capacity + 1;
    buf = new ArrayList<E>(Collections.nCopies(n, (E) null));
}

public int capacity() {
    return n - 1;
}

private int wrapIndex(int i) {
    int m = i % n;
    if (m < 0) { // modulus can be negative
        m += n;
    }
    return m;
}

@Override
public int size() {
    return this.size;
}

@Override
public E get(int i) {
    if (i < 0 || i >= n-1) throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();

    if(i > size()) throw new NullPointerException("Index is greater than size.");

    return buf.get(wrapIndex(leader + i));
}

@Override
public E set(int i, E e) {
    if (i < 0 || i >= n-1) {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    }
    if(i == size()) // assume leader's position as invalid (should use insert(e))
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("The size of the list is " + size() + " while the index was " + i
                +". Please use insert(e) method to fill the list.");
    return buf.set(wrapIndex(leader - size + i), e);
}

public void insert(E e)
{
    int s = size();     
    buf.set(wrapIndex(leader), e);
    leader = wrapIndex(++leader);
    buf.set(leader, null);
    if(s == n-1)
        return; // we have replaced the eldest element.
    this.size++;

}

@Override
public void clear()
{
    int cnt = wrapIndex(leader-size());
    for(; cnt != leader; cnt = wrapIndex(++cnt))
        this.buf.set(cnt, null);
    this.size = 0;      
}

public E removeOldest() {
    int i = wrapIndex(leader+1);

    for(;;i = wrapIndex(++i)) {
        if(buf.get(i) != null) break;
        if(i == leader)
            throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot remove element."
                    + " CircularArrayList is empty.");
    }

    this.size--;
    return buf.set(i, null);
}

@Override
public String toString()
{
    int i = wrapIndex(leader - size());
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder(size());

    for(; i != leader; i = wrapIndex(++i)){
        str.append(buf.get(i));
    }
    return str.toString();
}

public E getOldest(){
    int i = wrapIndex(leader+1);

    for(;;i = wrapIndex(++i)) {
        if(buf.get(i) != null) break;
        if(i == leader)
            throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot remove element."
                    + " CircularArrayList is empty.");
    }

    return buf.get(i);
}

public E getNewest(){
    int i = wrapIndex(leader-1);
    if(buf.get(i) == null)
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Error while retrieving the newest element. The Circular Array list is empty.");
    return buf.get(i);
}
}
```

Comment: This might be the source you're referring to: http://www.museful.net/2011/software-development/circulararraylist-for-java

Comment: I tried this code.  
CircularArrayList<String> buf = new CircularArrayList<String>(4);  
buf.insert("A");  
buf.insert("B");  
System.out.println(buf); //[null, null]  
buf.insert("C");  
buf.insert("D");  
System.out.println(buf); //[null, A, B, C]  
String res = buf.get(0); //null  
The code at  
http://www.museful.net/2011/software-development/circulararraylist-for-java  
works better for me.

Comment: The associated iterator is broken

Answer (score 2):

A very interesting project is disruptor. It has a ringbuffer and is used from what I know in financial applications.

See here: [code of ringbuffer](https://github.com/LMAX-Exchange/disruptor/blob/master/src/main/java/com/lmax/disruptor/RingBuffer.java)

I checked both Guava's EvictingQueue and ArrayDeque.

ArrayDeque does not limit growth if it's full it will double size and hence is not precisely acting like a ringbuffer.

EvictingQueue does what it promises but internally uses a Deque to store things and just bounds memory.

Hence, if you care about memory being bounded ArrayDeque is not fullfilling your promise. If you care about object count EvictingQueue uses internal composition (bigger object size).

A simple and memory efficient one can be stolen from [jmonkeyengine](https://github.com/jMonkeyEngine/jmonkeyengine/blob/master/jme3-ios/src/main/java/com/jme3/util/RingBuffer.java).
verbatim copy

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

public class RingBuffer<T> implements Iterable<T> {

  private T[] buffer;          // queue elements
  private int count = 0;          // number of elements on queue
  private int indexOut = 0;       // index of first element of queue
  private int indexIn = 0;       // index of next available slot

  // cast needed since no generic array creation in Java
  public RingBuffer(int capacity) {
    buffer = (T[]) new Object[capacity];
  }

  public boolean isEmpty() {
    return count == 0;
  }

  public int size() {
    return count;
  }

  public void push(T item) {
    if (count == buffer.length) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Ring buffer overflow");
    }
    buffer[indexIn] = item;
    indexIn = (indexIn + 1) % buffer.length;     // wrap-around
    count++;
  }

  public T pop() {
    if (isEmpty()) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Ring buffer underflow");
    }
    T item = buffer[indexOut];
    buffer[indexOut] = null;                  // to help with garbage collection
    count--;
    indexOut = (indexOut + 1) % buffer.length; // wrap-around
    return item;
  }

  public Iterator<T> iterator() {
    return new RingBufferIterator();
  }

  // an iterator, doesn't implement remove() since it's optional
  private class RingBufferIterator implements Iterator<T> {

    private int i = 0;

    public boolean hasNext() {
        return i < count;
    }

    public void remove() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    public T next() {
        if (!hasNext()) {
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        }
        return buffer[i++];
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: LIFO ring buffers may be helpful in overflow situations. imagine you provide timestamped data and you care more about recent timestamps than old ones. instead of dropping the newest elements in a queue impelmentation you drop the oldest from a stack. this is specially true for automation that does mitigation.

Comment: The iterator code for this is wrong.  It will return items in the wrong order, since it doesn't do the wrapping around correctly.

Answer (score 1):

None of the previously given examples were meeting my needs completely, so I wrote my own queue that allows following functionality: iteration, index access, indexOf, lastIndexOf, get first, get last, offer, remaining capacity, expand capacity, dequeue last, dequeue first, enqueue / add element, dequeue / remove element, subQueueCopy, subArrayCopy, toArray, snapshot, basics like size, remove or contains.

[EjectingQueue](https://gist.github.com/shathor/007a66c731592012bd9a)

[EjectingIntQueue](https://gist.github.com/shathor/44de9daa5807aa05dfc1)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to import some library just for that, you can use a Deque as a queue and wrap the RingBuffer logic around it:

```
import java.util.ArrayDeque;
import java.util.Deque;

public class RingBuffer<E> {
   private final Deque<E> queue;
   private final int size;

   public RingBuffer(final int size) {
       queue = new ArrayDeque<>(size);
       this.size = size;
   }

   public void add(final E e) {
       if (queue.size() == size) {
           queue.poll();
       }
       queue.add(e);
   }

   public E poll() {
       return queue.poll();
   }

   @Override
   public String toString() {
       return queue.toString();
   }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Use a [Queue](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html)

```
Queue<String> qe=new LinkedList<String>();

qe.add("a");
qe.add("b");
qe.add("c");
qe.add("d");

System.out.println(qe.poll()); //returns a
System.out.println(qe.poll()); //returns b
System.out.println(qe.poll()); //returns c
System.out.println(qe.poll()); //returns d
```

There's five simple methods of a [Queue](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html)

- element()  --  Retrieves, but does not remove, the head of this
  queue.
- offer(E o) -- Inserts the specified element into this queue, if
  possible.
- peek()     -- Retrieves, but does not remove, the head of    this
  queue, returning null if this queue is empty.
- poll()     --    Retrieves and removes the head of this queue, or
  null if this queue is empty.
- remove()   -- Retrieves and removes the head of this queue.

Comment: This keeps all elements, not just the last 4