# Is there non-concurrent (other than ArrayBlockingQueue) standard implementation of cyclic queue?

Tags: java, collections, concurrency, queue, circular-buffer

Is there a standard fast Java queue/circular-buffer structure like `ArrayBlockingQueue`, backed by an array, but without any concurrency synchronisation overhead?

Comment: BTW Disruptor is significantly faster than the built in ring buffers if you need higher performance or flexibility.

Comment: @PeterLawrey +1 but question in this case is about very small proof-of-concept in image manipulation (store last X pixels while iterating) and I just wanted to save some time on cyclic array implementation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is, and it's called [ArrayDeque](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html)

Comment: Is it thread-safe? But the docs say _They are not thread-safe_.

Comment: +1 Sorry, my mistake. It is not thread safe and isn't slowed down by this.

Answer (score 0):

If you need **fixed-size** queue / ring-buffer without synchronization it seems you would need to write it yourself.
You could also use some alternative options such as  apache commons `CircularFifoBuffer`.
Please see more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7266042/java-ring-buffer).