# textview set maxline = 10 ,11 line how update On the screen

Tags: android, textview

```
    sv = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.sv);// sv == tv parent view
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
    tv.setMaxLines(10);
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        String t1 = "---------------------"+i+"--------------- \n";
        tv.append(t1);
    }
    tv.append("dddddddddddddddddd \n");// 11 line
```

this is game chat panel ,when chat info excessive ,Whether can delete old lines ,Such as lines > 500 delete 1-200 line or delete 1 line update new 501 line ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add scroll inside of textView with:

```
android:scrollbars="vertical"
```

or You can delete first line with this before adding 11th line according to your code:

```
String arr[] = myTextView.getText().toString().split("\n",2);
myTextView.setText(arr[1]);
```

Comment: lines Exceed 300 Low efficiency!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a huge `TextView`, consider using a `ListView` with a [circular buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7266042/java-ring-buffer) adapter that caps the number of rows (messages) efficiently and enables smooth scrolling.