# Is there a cyclic List,Queue, whatever else in standard Java libraries?

Tags: java, collections

I am looking for cyclic collection in Java. I have some players in `Array` (they wait for their turn) but I would like to change `Array` to cyclic collection so it will be easier to get next player.(I know how it can be done otherwise, but I'd like to use cyclic collection already prepared in Java).

Comment: Have you considered a queue? But otherwise, no, a cyclic collection isn't in the standard Java libraries as far as I know.

Comment: @user3580294 Queue is not cyclic as far as I remember.

Comment: apache commons collection has one.

Comment: But you can make it behave like it's cyclic. Pop something off, do something with it, push it back on after.

Comment: A common way is `next = (current + 1) % total`

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7266042/java-ring-buffer

Comment: What @Ypnypn said.  There is rarely a need to get any more complicated than that.

Answer (score 0):

You can make any `Iterable` into a cyclic collection. Just keep requesting `Iterator`s forever.

```
class Ring<T> implements Iterable<T> {
    // Source of all Iterators.
    final Iterable<T> it;
    // Current Iterator we are consuming.
    Iterator<T> i;

    public Ring(Iterable<T> it) {
        this.it = it;
        i = it.iterator();
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<T> iterator() {
        return new Iterator<T> () {

            @Override
            public boolean hasNext() {
                // There's always a next for a Ring.
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public T next() {
               if ( !i.hasNext() ) {
                   // Iterator is exhausted - make a new one!
                   i = it.iterator();
               }
               return i.next();
            }

        };
    }
}

public void test() {
    Ring<String> r = new Ring<>(Arrays.asList("One", "Two", "Three"));
    int printed = 0;
    for (String s : r) {
        System.out.println(s);
        if (++printed > 10) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that there is a strange edge case when the wrapped `Iterable` delivers empty iterators but I leave that detail to the student.

Comment: Is it only I that read "make a new one!" like a little kid saying "let's have more cake!"?

Comment: @AndrewG - Nope! :) Me too.