# Implementing fifo in an array

Tags: android, arrays, eclipse

I have an array and I want to implement FIFO. my project consist of 5 games and a score for each individual game. I had already coded it. heres my code:

```
if (Game.isNewScore) {
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    if (addition[i] == 0) {
        addition[i] = Game.score;
        break;
        }
    }
}
```

now my problem is when Im already in the sixth game the scoring should replace the score in the 1st game then transfering the scores from left but it seems the score from the `game 6` is not showing.

**e.g**

2 4 6 8 9 - scores

1 2 3 4 5 - no. of Games

`when on sixth game`

4 6 8 9 (new score)

can someone teach me on this kind of logic? when you seems not getting my point please tell me. Im badly needing a help. thanks

Comment: use ArrayList ... add element check if size <= desired games count. if not, then remove first element ... just have to say this: it is basic programming problem ... you should know how to do this before starting writing any program

Comment: You need to use a FIFO array? Am i right? Have you tried ArrayList?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7266042/java-ring-buffer

Comment: @Selvin please apologize sir if Im not intelligent as you are. btw. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your best for this would be to change `addition` for `int[]` to `ArrayList<Integer>`. Your code could look something like this then :

```
ArrayList<Integer> addition = new ArrayList<>();
/*some other code....

*/
    if(Game.isNewScore) {
        if (addition.size() == 5){
            addition.remove(0);
        }
        addition.add(Game.score);
    }
```