# Get last n elements from stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am wondering is there an alternative to

```
List<X> lastN = all.subList(Math.max(0, all.size() - n), all.size());
```

with [*stream*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) usage?

Comment: I don't think this is generally possible with streams, as a stream's size may not be known a priori, or it may even be infinite. And if you create the stream from a list, just use sublist, as you did.

Comment: @tobias_k the OP seems to have a finite list however...

Comment: If you already have a list, then `subList` is the way to go.  You can then copy it, stream it, whatever else you want.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

A custom collector can be written like this:

```
public static <T> Collector<T, ?, List<T>> lastN(int n) {
    return Collector.<T, Deque<T>, List<T>>of(ArrayDeque::new, (acc, t) -> {
        if(acc.size() == n)
            acc.pollFirst();
        acc.add(t);
    }, (acc1, acc2) -> {
        while(acc2.size() < n && !acc1.isEmpty()) {
            acc2.addFirst(acc1.pollLast());
        }
        return acc2;
    }, ArrayList::new);
}
```

And use it like this:

```
List<String> lastTen = input.stream().collect(lastN(10));
```

Comment: You don’t need to write `ArrayList<T>::new`, just `ArrayList::new` is enough as method references always use type inference rather than raw types (like if the “diamond operator” was always present when using `::new`). You already use it with `ArrayDeque::new`. Btw. I’d prefer `removeFirst`/`removeLast` over `pollFirst`/`pollLast` here…

Comment: @Holger, first I wrote `ArrayList::new`, but Eclipse displayed a warning about unchecked constructor. Well, probably that's an ECJ-specific problem.

Comment: Interestingly, the `ArrayDeque::new` would benefit from a type witness, as using `ArrayDeque<T>::new` would make the type witness at the `Collector.of` call obsolete (and `<T>` is simpler than `<T, Deque<T>, List<T>>`) whereas the type witness at `ArrayList<T>::new` is not necessary as its type can be inferred from the target type.

Answer (score 41):

Use [Stream.skip()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#skip-long-)

> Returns a stream consisting of the remaining elements of this stream after discarding the first n elements of the stream. If this stream contains fewer than n elements then an empty stream will be returned.

```
all.stream().skip(Math.max(0, all.size() - n)).forEach(doSomething);
```

Comment: This doesn't return the last n elements. It skips the first n. not what OP asked for.

Comment: what if we do not know about stream size (assume worst case)?

Comment: This throws `IllegalArgumentException` if `all.size() < n`. The `Math.max(0, all.size() - n)` from the original question will be necessary here as well.

Answer (score 4):

In case the stream has unknown size, there's probably no way around consuming the entire stream and buffering the last `n` elements encountered so far. You can do this using some kind of deque, or a specialized ring-buffer automatically maintaining its maximum size (see [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7266042/java-ring-buffer) for some implementations).

```
public static <T> List<T> lastN(Stream<T> stream, int n) {
    Deque<T> result = new ArrayDeque<>(n);
    stream.forEachOrdered(x -> {
        if (result.size() == n) {
            result.pop();
        }
        result.add(x);
    });
    return new ArrayList<>(result);
}
```

All of those operations (`size`, `pop`, `add`) should have complexity of *O(1)*, so the overall complexity for a stream with (unknown) length *n* would be *O(n)*.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes I need a "oneliner" (in this case a three liner) as creating a collector is just too much fuss.

If the stream is small then it is possible to `reverse`, `limit` and `reverse` again without much sacrificing performance. This will result the last n elements.

It is useful if filtering is required as in that case it is not possible to specify the size.

```
Stream.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
  .filter(i -> i % 2 == 0)
  .sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder())
  .limit(2)
  .sorted(Comparator.naturalOrder())
  .forEach(System.out::println); // prints 6 8
```

Comment: Shouldn't the second sort use natural order instead of reverse order?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I updated the answer.
Also it is important to note that my this solution works on ordered lists.