# java 8 - circular buffer

Tags: java, buffer, circular-buffer

What is the best implementation of a Circular Buffer in Java? I have read [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7266042/java-ring-buffer) but they're old and refer to [CircularFifoBuffer](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.2/org/apache/commons/collections/buffer/CircularFifoBuffer.html) which isn't present in Apache Commons Collections 4. Is there a new, widely accepted way to use a circular buffer in Java 8?

Comment: Well, there's [CircularFifoQueue](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-4.2/org/apache/commons/collections4/queue/CircularFifoQueue.html) which might be want you want. Btw, the "circular-dependency" tag seems to be wrong here - or did I miss something?

Comment: Seems you forgot to read [the answer by T. Baum](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11842123/5772882)?

Comment: I think the CircularFifoBuffer was removed to CircularFifoQueue, thank you very much! About the tag, it was definitely a mistake, I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

### For a growable circular buffer: [`java.util.ArrayDeque`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html).

The `ArrayDeque` class is still a bit overlooked.

You need to define *circular buffer* more precisely, though. The classical definition suggests a bounded buffer with a capacity that is never changed. I doubt that this is optimal but for a few purposes. This is why my first suggestion is the built-in `ArrayDeque` class.

From the documentation:

> Resizable-array implementation of the `Deque` interface. Array deques
> have no capacity restrictions; they grow as necessary to support
> usage. … This class is likely to be faster than `Stack` when used as a
> stack, and faster than `LinkedList` when used as a queue.
>
> **Since:**
>
> 1.6

The documentation doesn’t state directly that it’s circular, but it is (I just inspected the source code to be 100 % sure). Since they recommend using it as a queue, it doesn’t really make sense not to make it circular.

### For a fixed-capacity circular buffer: Roll your own subclass

If for some reason that I cannot see from here you need a circular buffer that rejects elements beyond some predefined maximum element count, I can’t imagine that it would be hard to write a thin subclass of `ArrayDeque` that implements the behaviour.

**Link:** [Circular buffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer) on Wikipedia. Quote:

> ... a circular buffer... is a data structure that uses a single,
> fixed-size buffer ...

Comment: The quote from documentation says _`Array deques have no capacity restrictions`_ which means it will grow unbounded. So, it is completely opposite to the requirement in question - circular buffers will wrap and will not grow beyond specified limits.

Comment: @uvsmtid You may be right that I have stretched the definition of *circular buffer* a bit.

Comment: I don't see any reason why someone DVed this correct answer.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash Thanks. I believe that the reason is in the comment by uvsmtid. Some pedants are more focused on whether the question is answered literally as asked than whether the answer is helpful to the readers of the question. I have nevertheless added a section at the end taking the classical definition of *circular buffer* literally.

Comment: ArvindKumarAvinash Thanks. I believe that the reason is in the comment by @uvsmtid. Some pedants are more focused on whether the question is answered literally as asked than whether the answer is helpful to the readers of the question. I have nevertheless added a section at the end taking the classical definition of *circular buffer* literally.