# Dictionary with limited size that removes oldest elements?

Tags: c#, data-structures

Is there an existing data structure usable for hashing data that will give ability to delete the oldest element?

The approach that I am thinking of right now is to have a Dictionary and a Queue having fast lookup using the Dictionary and being able to delete oldest element from the Dictionary using a Queue.

Comment: Will you need to remove elements other than the oldest? And will you need to store a lot of elements - in other words, how important is performance on such deletes?

Comment: What type of Data with this potential collection be storing..?

Comment: To delete the oldest element you need a set size or time to...

Comment: You may want a circular buffer. maybe see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/590069/how-would-you-code-an-efficient-circular-buffer-in-java-or-c-sharp

Comment: Wouldn't an `OrderedDictionary` be useful here? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132577.aspx

Comment: @keyboardP, I think your comment satisfies current requirements (also removal of first entry will likely be O(n) ).

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - Yup, assuming there's no other criterion I think an OrderedDictionary will be a good option for this.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use an [OrderedDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132577.aspx). This will maintain insertion order (unlike a `SortedDictionary` which will be ordered by keys). You can then remove the first available element which would considered the oldest.

Comment: +1. Note that removal of first element is O(n), which may be ok as question does not specify any timing requirements for that operation.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - Good point. Also to OP, if optimization is key then it may be worth testing capacity sizes to initialize the OrderedDictionary with http://www.dotnetperls.com/dictionary-optimization (although the article relates to the standard Dictionary collection, the principle should still apply)

Answer (score 3):

An OrderedDictionary is a good suggestion, but if you need types other than a string in your dictionary, try this;

```
public sealed class SizedDictionary<TKey, TValue> : Dictionary<TKey, TValue> {

private int maxSize;
private Queue<TKey> keys;

public SizedDictionary(int size) {
    maxSize = size;
    keys = new Queue<TKey>();
}

new public void Add (TKey key, TValue value) {
    if (key==null) throw new ArgumentNullException();
    base.Add(key, value);
    keys.Enqueue(key);
    if (keys.Count > maxSize) base.Remove(keys.Dequeue());
}

new public bool Remove (TKey key) {
    if (key==null) throw new ArgumentNullException();
    if (!keys.Contains(key)) return false;
    var newQueue = new Queue<TKey>();
    while (keys.Count>0) {
        var thisKey = keys.Dequeue();
        if (!thisKey.Equals(key)) newQueue.Enqueue(thisKey);
    }
    keys=newQueue;
    return base.Remove(key);
}
}
```

I'm using a sealed class because we are just hiding the add and remove methods, so if this class were to be inherited it wouldn't be clear which version was used. A more complete solution would use an internal dictionary and not inherit, but that would be a lot more long winded

Answer (score 0):

`System.Collections.Generic.SortedList` is just a dictionary that sorts by key.  If the key is temporal in some way, you can simply use `RemoveAt` to remove the first element when you reach a certain size when you want to add another entry.

Likely, since you mentioned `Dictionary`, you probably don't have a temporal key.  But, a `Dictionary` is just a collection of `KeyValuePair<K,V>` objects.  So, you could have a sorted list where the value is a `KeyValuePair<K,V>` and the key is the date/time the element was added.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a specific requirement I'd implement the
Dictionary with a Queue / Buffer behind (e.g. circular buffer mentioned in comments).

OrderedDictionary is a good choice and a good source on how to do that (I don't want to post it here but you can find it easily) - you just need something better than an ArrayList to hold your elements (and do the dequeueing)- since you're constantly removing the 'first'.

Comment: "_a good source on how to do that (I don't want to post it here but you can find it easily)_" -- is there a specific, secret source for understanding `OrderedDictionary`s I should be looking for here?

Comment: @ruffin what I meant is go google (or duckduckgo:) "OrderedDictionary source code" or something of that sort. If I remember correctly (it was many yrs ago) the actual OrderedDictionary implementation can show you how to whip up your own specific dictionary for specific purposes. I didn't want to post the link as at that time .NET was closed source.

Comment: Gotcha. Was confused why you needed "a good source" for one [as if MS' was broken](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#methods), but you literally meant [get some good source \[code\] for one](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/3b1eaf5203992df69de44c783a3eda37d3d4cd10/System/compmod/system/collections/specialized/ordereddictionary.cs). Thanks!