# Using a circular/ring buffer in Android

Tags: android, stringbuffer, circular-buffer

I have been searching online for some time and I cant find any information about circular / ring buffers for Android.
I tried to use the `ByteBuffer` but it is not doing what I want.

I would like o have a simple circular buffer, that have start and end pointer, all this automatic and overwrites old data, It would be perfect if it could be a String buffer as I need to save actually messages similar to:

`"$messageA#"`

`"$messageB#"`

`"$messageC#"`

`"$messageD#"`

Any idea?
Thanks!

Comment: See this previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/590069/how-would-you-code-an-efficient-circular-buffer-in-java-or-c-sharp