# Implementing Circular Buffer

Tags: java

Found this interview question and trying to solve it with Java.

> Q:Design a function to gives real time statistics of your web
>   traffic,count one day's website visit ，count one week's website visit.

I understand that this will require a circular data structure. Which one will be appropriate in case of Java implementation `CircularBuffer` or `Circular LinkedList`.
If circular buffer is not right solution then what is?

Comment: I do not see anything related to circular buffers here.

Comment: What make you think a circular buffer would be an appropriate structure for this process?

Comment: I guess, It would require to capture data in every 7 days. Circular Buffer has O(1) complexity of retrieving and adding the data. If you think of a better solution, please let me know.

Comment: huh? Where is this circular thing here ?

Comment: What's the difference between a "circular buffer" and a "circular linked list"? Isn't a buffer a *use* of a linked list? Are you asking about a specific implementation?

Comment: I am not sure if Java API has a circular buffer/linkedlist implementation out of the box. Yes I am asking about the implementation if possible.

Comment: @HimanshuYadav see [java-ring-buffer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7266042/java-ring-buffer) **, or** [how-would-you-code-an-efficient-circular-buffer-in-java-or-c-sharp?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/590069/how-would-you-code-an-efficient-circular-buffer-in-java-or-c-sharp?lq=1)

Answer (score 1):

I would do this like this.

```
private long dayCount = 0;
private long lastSixDaysCount = 0;

// called once per day
public void rollDayCount() {
    saveDayCountToDB(dayCount);
    lastSixDaysCount = sumLastSixDaysFromDB();
    dayCount = 0;
}

public void incrementCount() {
    dayCount++;
}

public long getDayCount() {
    return dayCount;
}

public long getWeekCount() {
    return dayCount + lastSixDaysCount;
}
```

If you need to, you can make the fields `volatile` and `synchronized` on `incrementCount()`

Comment: Thanks for the implementation. How would this data be kept?Lets say I want to access count for a day `Monday`?

Comment: @HimanshuYadav I would store it in some database or file.  You want to be able to keep this information even if the process dies or is restarted.  You don't want to wait a week for the counts to be repopulated as you might need to restart the application after a week.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing to do with circular buffers - however, have a look at [Buffer Utils from apache](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/BufferUtils.html)

The trick is to drop data when you capacity is exceeded, you can do this by creating an array with fixed size. Then use a readpointer and writerpointer. when the writepointer overlaps and is at the same position with the readpointer, move both.

If you show your existing code, we'll help you.

Comment: I didn't write any code yet. Still trying to come up with a proper data structure.

Answer (score 0):

If it is simply counting the no of visitors than it is a tricky multithreading question to count no of unique visitors. This is one of the best places where you can use `AtomicInteger`.

```
AtomicInteger atomicInteger = new  AtomicInteger();
public void increment(){
    Integer present=null;
    Integer expect=null;
    do{
        present=atomicInteger.get();
        expect = present+1;
    }while(!atomicInteger.compareAndSet(present, expect));
}
```

If you have to clear it after some threshold than it's also simple. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a [CircularFifoBuffer](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/buffer/CircularFifoBuffer.html) is what you are looking for. As others wrote, I don't know if a circular structure is really what you need, but the Common-Collection-Utils from Apache already implement a circular buffer