# Circular buffer implementation in Android

Tags: java, android, c

How can we achieve Circular buffer implementation in Android?

Is there a way we can re-use a pre-defined method if exists? or do we have support for C standard libraries in Android?

Comment: did u read this ?    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/590069/how-would-you-code-an-efficient-circular-buffer-in-java-or-c-sharp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Android development first preference is to use Java rather than C for implementing these things. Ofcourse you can do that in C (using JNI) but that requires certain overheads i.e. you need to implement your own garbage collection logic along with the code of circular buffer whereas in Java this can be achieved automatically. . See below class if it works for your case..

```
import java.nio.BufferOverflowException;
import java.nio.BufferUnderflowException;

public class CustomCircularBuffer<T> {

  private T[] buffer;

  private int tail;

  private int head;


  public CustomCircularBuffer(int n) {
    buffer = (T[]) new Object[n];
    tail = 0;
    head = 0;
  }

  public void add(T toAdd) {
    if (head != (tail - 1)) {
        buffer[head++] = toAdd;
    } else {
        throw new BufferOverflowException();
    }
    head = head % buffer.length;
  }

  public T get() {
    T t = null;
    int adjTail = tail > head ? tail - buffer.length : tail;
    if (adjTail < head) {
        t = (T) buffer[tail++];
        tail = tail % buffer.length;
    } else {
        throw new BufferUnderflowException();
    }
    return t;
  }

  public String toString() {
    return "CustomCircularBuffer(size=" + buffer.length + ", head=" + head + ", tail=" + tail + ")";
  }
}
```

Here are some other useful links which can give necessary explanations ..

[Example](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0140__Collections/CircularBuffer.htm)

[Another Example](http://www.sanfoundry.com/java-program-circular-buffer/)

[In Depth Article](http://www.vias.org/javacourse/chap16_04.html)

Answer (score 4):

I just realized that [ArrayDeque](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html) would be a good implementation for this.

There is also [CircularArray](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/util/CircularArray.html) from Android support.

> CircularArray is a generic circular array data structure that provides
>   O(1) random read, O(1) prepend and O(1) append. The CircularArray
>   automatically grows its capacity when number of added items is over
>   its capacity.

I can't tell its performance, <del>but from a quick glance at the Javadocs, it seems to be designed with efficiency in mind.</del> Not so sure anymore.

Comment: Thanks for the information. On other note, you guys should be aware that certain CircularBuffer implementations set the capacity of the array to be static while others does so dynamic. Android's CircularArray and Java's ArrayDeque does so dynamically, which to some of us will requires custom implementation for a static capacity

Comment: @OzShabat do you happen to have a static-capacity ArrayDeque implemented?

Comment: Nope, sorry. It's been long since I dealt with this